# Microsoft USD - Change URL based on CaseID

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

I am new to Microsoft Unified Service Desk, therefore please pardon me if i make any mistake.

My scenario is when a call is received by a call center agent in Unified Service Desk then initially he will create a case for the particular customer and initially the caseID will be null therefore call center agent will see a new case window where he can create a case. Once the case is created he will save the details and the caseID will also be saved. Now, in the next step he will transfer the call to the supervisor and in this case the supervisor will not see a new case window instead he will have the details in-front of him of that particular customer that were saved earlier.

But how will i achieve that do i have to create a hosted control and is there a way i can execute JavaScript inside hosted control.

Looking forward to your help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is.

1. Create 2 Action Calls.
2. 1st Action Call for New Case with Action **New CRM Page**.
3. 2nd Action Call for Open Case with Action **Open CRM Page**.
4. Put Condition inside **Action 1** [[$Settings.YourCaseID]]==""
5. Put Condition inside **Action 2** [[$Settings.YourCaseID]]!=""
6. Create another Action with **SaveSetting** Action and **CRM Global Manager** hosted control.
7. Once the case is saved fire the third action call (It will save the CaseID inside $Setting).
8. Now when the case is transferred it will open the case with SavedID.